# spring-saml multi-tenant - 1 webapp with multi SPs

Tags: multi-tenant, spring-saml

I've deployed 1 webapplication (WAR) to Tomcat behind context root /myApp

The application is exposed to the public by means of 2 public HTTPS URLs:

- Eg. https://a.this.that and https//b.this.that

Both these public requests arrive in that same application (/myApp).

Now I need this webapplication to support 2 SAML service providers.
Both will use the same IDP.

- How should I configure Spring SAML in order for this application to support two SPs, one for the first URL, and one for the second ?
- What ACS location URLs should I put in my service provider XML ?
- Do I need multiple SP XML files and/or do I need to define extended service provider metadata to get this working ?
- Do I need a spring saml multi-tenant setup to get this working and if so what is the relationship between the entityId and the URL ? Or can all this be achieved in a different way without a multi-tenant setup ?

Could somebody provide some sample xml metadata, spring saml config that demonstrates how the above could be achieved ?

Kr,

EDH

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to generate SP metadata for each of the instances separately, and add it to the metadata manager. The URLs will be `a.this.that` in the first one, and `b.this.that` in the other. You also need to set entity alias to differentiate the two instances. See the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-entity-alias) for more details.